# How to add a button to the right hand side of a UITableView entry?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, button

I am working on an in app purchase app. I would like fill a table view with a list of products,
and put a BUY button on the right hand side of each entry. Does anyone have the UITableView - fu necessary to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class that extends UITableViewCell

```
@interface CustomTblCell : UITableViewCell
```

In the corresponding NIB `CustomTblCell.xib`  drag and drop UILabel and UIButton elements (side-by-side).

Finally, in your method `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` initialize and return the CustomTblCell

Hope this helps!

Here is a code snippet for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I mentioned above

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"customCellIndentifier";

    CustomTblCell *cell = (CustomTblCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTblCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.label.text = @"My Product";
    return cell;
}
```

If you have many rows in your table such that the user has to scroll through the table use 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. This optimizes the code to reuse the same customTblCell object which is now not in user view.  The deque method takes a String as input arg (customTableCellIdentifier). Make sure this matches the Identifier string you specify in the IB while creating the CustomTblCell

Comment: Thanks. That works. My actual solution involved loading up a view controller with this nib: one line instead of two seemed more elegant.